# How to list all anonymous (so IP-public) edits made to Wikipedia from a specific IP address?

Tags: python, ip-address, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

Lets say I have an IP address, for example the [IP address of the Hungarian Parliament](https://www.whatismyip.com/193.224.28.151/): `193.224.28.151`

**How can I get a list of all Wikipeida edits made using this IP address?**

On [a Tom Scott webpage](https://www.tomscott.com/wikiparliament/), I read:

> Here's a fact: Wikipedia stores the IP addresses of anonymous users.
>
> Here's another fact: all of the web traffic from the Houses of
> Parliament is sent through one of two proxy servers — which means that
> every anonymous edit to Wikipedia from within Parliament is attributed
> to one of just two IP addresses.
>
> I'm sure you can see where this is going.

I haven't found a repository for a project like this. If it can be done either within browser or maybe using Python, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Special:Contributions page to view contributions from a Wikipedia account, IP address or IP range. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/193.224.28.151 lists the edits made from 193.224.28.151. You may also view edits from an IP range, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/193.224.28.0/22.

If you wish to view contributions from Wikipedia accounts and individual IP addresses via Wikipedia's API, documentation and examples are available at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Usercontribs

Answer (score 2):

Using **Pywikibot** you may use the MediaWiki API as follows:

```
import pywikibot
site = pywikibot('Wikipedia:en')
user = pyikibot.User(site, '193.224.28.2')
```

User is a class derived from pywikibot.Page which represents a user and there is a method to retrieve his contibutions. The method is **contributions()** which is a generator and yields *pywikibot.Page* (a Page object which can be used for further informations) , *revid* (the revision id), *pywikibot.Timestamp* (an object derived from datetime), comment (the edit summary). To get the last 5 Edits you may use:

```
contribs = list(user.contributions(total=5))
```

This retrieves entries like:

```
(Page('History of Croatia'), 282343057, Timestamp(2009, 4, 7, 14, 10, 7), '')
```

To get a range of ips you may use the corresponding site method **usercontibs()** but you have to upcast the content by yourself:

```
list(site.usercontribs(userprefix='193.224.28.', total=5))
```

For each entry you get a dict like this:

```
{'comment': '',
 'ns': 0,
 'pageid': 5574,
 'parentid': 281875336,
 'revid': 282343057,
 'timestamp': '2009-04-07T14:10:07Z',
 'title': 'History of Croatia',
 'user': '193.224.28.2',
 'userid': 0}
```

There are additional parameters for *Site.usercontribs()* method which are als usable for *Page.contributions()*. They can be used to filter the result, e.g. for a specific namespace or to retrieve only the topmost edit of pages. The documentation can be found [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.site.html?highlight=usercontribs#pywikibot.site._generators.GeneratorsMixin.usercontribs).